# Arrays initialization on constructors

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, constructor, initialization

I'm trying to convert a program to OOP. The program works with a few arrays:

```
int tipoBilletes[9] = { 500,300,200,100,50,20,10,1,2 };
int cantBilletes[9] = {0};
```

So for my conversion, I declared in the header file this:

```
int *tipoBilletes;
int *cantBilletes;
```

and in the constructor I wrote

```
tipoBilletes = new int[9];
cantBilletes = new int[9];

tipoBilletes[0] = 500;
tipoBilletes[1] = 300;
tipoBilletes[2] = 200;
...
```

It works fine.

My question is, is there any way to initialize it like in Java?

```
int[] tipoBilletes = new int[]{ 500,300 };
```

rather than having to set each element one by one?

Comment: Not until the new version of C++ comes out. But you should be using `std::vector`, not `new[]`. Also, what benefits are you gaining by changing it from a fixed-size array to a dynamic array?

Comment: I *still* can't comprehend how it's not possible to have something as simple as a plain local array of objects without a default constructor in old C++... Have they, like, forgotten about it when making C++03, or what?

Comment: well i used dynamic array , cuz i thought that i could do the initialization java - like

Comment: @Kos: What makes you think it's not possible?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition sorry, I can't really remember what I have meant, it's been a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is there any way to initialize it like in Java?

Yes, starting from [**C++11**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) there is a way to do this as shown below. Note that this was proposed in [p1009r2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1009r2.pdf).

```
int *tipoBilletes = new int[] { 500,300,200,100,50,20,10,1,2 };
```

From [new expression documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) the above creates an array of type `int[9]`.

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q45TM1ez1)

---

Note that you could just use `std::vector` that will do the memory management for you so that you don't have to worry about memory leaks. But the question was not about how to use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4):

No, but you don't necessarily nead to write out each assignment independently.  Another option would be:

```
const int TIPO_BILLETES_COUNT = 9;
const int initialData[TIPO_BILLETES_COUNT] = { 500,200,300,100,50,20,10,1,2 };
std::copy(initialData, initialData + TIPO_BILLETES_COUNT, tipoBilletes);
```

(Note that you should almost certainly be using a `std::vector` for this instead of manual dynamic allocation.  The initialization is no different with a `std::vector` though once you've `resize`d it.)

Comment: Actually, for the `std::vector` option, you could initialize the vector using its constructor that takes a pair of iterators instead of `std::copy`.

Comment: @Fred:  Yep, you could do that too!

Answer (score 2):

If you use std::vector you can use [boost::assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html):

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp>  
//... 
using namespace boost::assign;
std::vector<int> tipoBilletes;
tipoBilletes += 500, 300, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 1, 2;
```

On the other hand, you should consider using the fixed-size array if it is small and constant size.