# Allocate array on heap with default initializer and without size

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I would like to allocate an array on the heap with default initializer. Since the initializer already knows the size, why do I have to provide it explicitely? Is there a way not to tell it the size and still get it right?

Specifically: Why does `int* arr = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };` work, but `int* arr2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };` does not, even though it can clearly infer the size to be 3?

This is odd to me, especially since this works just fine on the stack: `int arr3[] = { 1, 2, 3 }`?

### Code in Context

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int* arr = nullptr;

const int* getArr() {
  if (!arr) {
    int* arr = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 }; // this works
    // int* arr2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }; // this does not work
    // int arr3[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; // yet, this works just fine
  }
  return arr;
}

int main() {
  auto arr = getArr();
  std::cout << "Hello, world: " << arr[0] << "\n";
}
```

## Results

I am using https://replit.com/languages/cpp.

It says:

```
> clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
main.cpp:8:25: error: expected expression
    int* arr2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
                        ^
main.cpp:8:21: error: excess elements in scalar initializer
    int* arr2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
                    ^        ~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
exit status 1
```

Comment: `auto* arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };` also works. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/95qThzW7a)

Comment: It works: https://godbolt.org/z/vdTzYjGx1 Where did you try it? Which compiler? What's the exact error message?

Comment: `std::vector<int> arr = { 1, 2, 3 };`

Comment: "not work" is not a sufficient problem description. Don't assume that things are obvious, often they are not

Comment: I provided the exact error messages and context of execution

Comment: btw the code is broken in any case. There are two `arr` in the code. The one that poitns to an array never makes it out of the function, because the one you return is the global `nullptr` which leads to undefined behavior when dereferencing it. Why is there a global in the first place?!?

Comment: @Domi See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72300088/12002570) where I give the reason why `auto* arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }` works.

Comment: This works just fine, even with clang [see it live here](https://godbolt.org/z/1hajGMfhb). BTW, your code leaks memory.

Comment: clang 7 and clang 8 have a problem with that, clang 9 and newer accept the code. The online compiler you are using uses a very old version of the compiler.

Comment: if replit uses an ancient compiler without c++11 support then its an error

Comment: @mch Can you write an answer, I'll accept it then? Because this seems to be it 100%. Funnily enough, after logging into repl.it, it uses a different compiler and just straight up works 

Comment: the answer is here already https://stackoverflow.com/a/72300088/4117728

Comment: Even though `new int[]{1, 2, 3}` works, there can still be reason to specify the number of elements explicitly; e.g. `new int[100] {1, 2, 3}` could be used to initialize all except the first 3 elements with 0...